# Implementing multiple language url nextjs and next-i18n-next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, next.js, i18next

I"m about to use the next-i18next internalization library.

https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next

I was wondering how I can change the language of the path of my url. Something like this:

/about-us

/over-ons  -> goes to dutch version of about us page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found any solution? Could please share it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set localeSubpaths in your next.config.js

next.config.js

```
const {nextI18NextRewrites} = require('next-i18next/rewrites');

const localeSubpaths = {
    en: 'en',
    fr: 'fr',
};

module.exports = {
    rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        localeSubpaths,
    },
};
```

i18n.js

```
const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next').default;
const {localeSubpaths} = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
    defaultLanguage: 'fr',
    otherLanguages: ['en'],
    defaultNS: 'common',
    browserLanguageDetection: false,
    serverLanguageDetection: false,
    localeSubpaths,
    localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales')
});
```